# Same as vs. same with

Tags: prepositions

Which is more correct:
a. Living under the same sky **as** you
b. Living under the same sky **with** you

And what’s the difference if there’s any?

Comment: *I live in the **same** house **as** you* and  *I live in the house **with** you* are both valid, and effectively mean the same (but the first emphasises the fact that we're ***in the same house***, where the second emphasises that we're ***together***). But *I live in the **same** house **with** you* is very peculiar phrasing that would require a very peculiar context to be considered "valid" (where the house must have already been mentioned in some other context unrelated to the fact that we both live there).

Comment: What part of those prepositions do you not understand? What do you think they mean?

Answer (score 1):

They are both correct.

In b., "with you" doesn't belong with "the same...", so it must modify "Living". So it implies that the speaker is living *with* the other person.

In a., "as you" modifies "the same sky". Now there is no suggestion of "with you". Perhaps the two people are not with each other, but they are apart -- but they are living under the same sky.

Answer (score 0):

Both your sentences are correct, but they are conveying two very different meanings.

I think "same as" implies similarity while "same with" implies indifference.

It's the same menu as yesterday.
Whether you come or not, it's the same with me.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So what's the difference in interpretation between the two sentences in the question?

Comment: I don't think "same with" means anything particular; your example sounds to me like a mix-up of "it's fine with me" and "it's all the same to me". As Rosie F points out, the example in the question works because it can be parsed as "living ... with you"